# Is a 120GB SSD enough for Windows 8 plus essentials?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, disk-space

I am looking to acquire an SSD but I am wondering if 120GB is enough or should I go with 250GB.

I am going to use Windows 8.1 and the biggest softwares installed will be:

- Battlefield 4 (may get to ~40GB in the future)
- Arma 2 (7.8GB)
- Arma 2: Operation Arrowhead (10.9GB)
- Arma 3 (10.9GB)
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (6.46GB)
- Plus some small essentials.

Am I going to regret buying a 120GB SSD?

Comment: Maybe this Q is opinion based. So, IMO, we *always end* needing more space...

Comment: @brasofilo - I think that the math would speak to the point that with OS and listed applications, there will be only 13% free space. At this point the OP should note that a free 15 GBs is probably not enough.

Comment: Games are essentials now? Regardless I would say its all opinion base, 120GB for a primary partition is tiny with real essentials only even I think... But my Wife has a laptop with 320GB and uses maybe 25GB total with Windows 8, Office 2010, and Firefox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do the math to see what you want to do. So this is not opinion, just simple math:

A 120 GB drive is not 120 GB - it is more like 111.7 (1024^2)

Give 20 GB + to Windows OS (the upcoming patches, security and what not)

Give 76.06 GB for what you have a listed space requirements

Now you are at about 15 GB free space or about 13% free. If you need more, you could stripe off what you are not using. The closer to FULL you get, you will notice an impact on SSD performance, even thought there is provisioning.

As @brasofilo stated in the comment, you are always going to need more space. I remember back in the day when the super huge 13 GB drives came out and I thought that there was no way to fill it, now I have 3 TB x 3 with 6 TB back up system. You can never have enough space. You should be asking should I go with a 250 or 500 if you really do not want to have to play flip, flop with adding removing programs for space.